# why return basic html source instead view when return view in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

***UPDATE:*** when send data to controller and get data from controller i don't know why show html source code,

this is my view for login

```
<section id="form">
<!--form-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Signup", new ViewDataDictionary());}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <h2 class="or">or</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @Html.Partial("_login")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

as you see two partial view, one for login and on for register in one view,
if user not registered or enter wrong password in login partial and cick on login button, in return from server, **browser show basic html code** of login page , in bellow there are my controller and my partialview

```
<section id="loginForm">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder ="Email" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "password" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RememberMe, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RememberMe)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RememberMe, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="pull-right col-md-3">
                <input type="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:#5d1338;color:white" />
            </div>
        </div>

    }
</section>
```

and in my control

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                MigrateShoppingCart(model.Email);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View("Login",model);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I could understand, you want to return only Login html "view" when the login request fails.

Why don't you just create a new **View** for this purpose and return it in the case of **SignInStatus.Failure** ?

Comment: I want: when user enter wrong pass show login page again, that contain 2 partial view (the sane as before enter user name or pass )again not show HTML page source ,